# MapBox LocationEngineProvider

Tags: java, android, mapbox

I am using the mapbox to show the location of the user on the map but when I want to implement "LocationEngineProvider" ide shows that it has some error and does not show any recommendations.

[Code Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrgVA.png)

Comment: Can you include the actual error?

Comment: 'LocationEngineProvider()' has private access in 'com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEngineProvider'

Comment: See answer. It should be sufficiently detailed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Mapbox Android Core 1.0.0` the constructor has been marked as `private`.
Use the Factory method to obtain an instance.

```
final LocationEngine locationEngine = LocationEngineProvider.getBestLocationEngine(this);
```

Also, the `setPriority` method has been removed. See the relative [GitHub commit](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-events-android/commit/ead0d8c5e01926d09dcbbd4a4b706e9216aa1fc7#diff-f30d9c26536d598f49a2e375aa2aec9f).

Most probably (I'm not a user of this library) you need use `LocationEngineRequest.Builder` to replace this type of instance creation.

Comment: That first part worked but the ".obtainBestLocationEngineAvailable ();" error 'Can not resolve method' obtainBestLocationEngineAvailable () '"

Comment: @EnzoPortela that's because the LocationEngine interface, which is returned by getBestLocationEngine, does not expose  such a method. See the commit https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-events-android/blob/2eacb1920502e69c75ab037e9fcd898ea7f822b6/liblocation/src/main/java/com/mapbox/android/core/location/LocationEngine.java
obtainBestLocationEngineAvailable has been replaced by that Factory method, getBestLocationEngine

Comment: @EnzoPortela let me know if you need help.

Comment: I still can not figure out how to use the ".obtainBestLocationEngineAvailable ()"? I'm watching this (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2rclnd8OKHU&t=161s) video is more out of date

Comment: @EnzoPortela obtainBestLocationEngineAvailable **does not exist** as of now. You just need to use LocationEngineProvider.getBestLocationEngine

Comment: What would be the substitute?

Comment: @EnzoPortela the current solution would be LocationEngineProvider.getBestLocationEngine(), as I wrote in the answer.

Comment: You have a project to example?

Comment: @EnzoPortela I've never used this library. I studied the MapBox project source code just for your question